# probability space of $100$ homeworks graded by two person

Tags: probability, measure-theory

> $100$ homeworks are on the table, with two questions to be graded. Andy is in charge
> of grading question one and Patrick is in charge of grading question two. First, Andy
> grades some homeworks at random; each homework has probability $0.3$ of being graded.
> Next, Patrick randomly grades half of the homeworks. That is, he grades $50$ homeworks.
> Assume Andy and Patrick make their choices independently. 
> (a) Write down the probability space $(S, P)$ based on the information
> given.
> (b) Let $N$ be the number of homeworks that Andy graded. What is $\mathbb E(N)$?
> (c) Let $M$ be the number of homeworks that Andy graded and Patrick did not grade.
> What is $\mathbb E (M)$?

For (a) I guess the $S$ the set of all $100$ homeworks. But I didn't understand how to assign probabibilities on the sigma algebra generated by this set.

For $(b)$ I guess it should be $\mathbb E(N)=100\times0.3=30$. Is it correct?

For $(c)$, the probability of homework graded by Andy and Patrick is $0.3$ and $0.5$ respectively. Then is it $\mathbb E(M)=0.3\times0.5$?

It will be a great help if anyone correct me if I am wrong. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Label the homeworks with $i=1,2,\dots,100$.

a)

The info that each homework has probability $0.3$ to be graded by Andy can be reworded immediately as: Andy graded $30$ homeworks.

Then for $S$ you can take the set:$$S:=\{(A,P)\in\mathcal P([100])^2:|A|=30\text{ and }|P|=50\}$$with equiprobability of all outcomes. Here $A$ stands for the subset of $[100]=\{1,2,\dots,100\}$ contain all labels of homeworks graded by Andy and $P$ corresponds similarly with Patrick.

b)

If we prescribe $A_{i}:S\to\mathbb R$ as $(A,P)\mapsto 1$ if $i\in A$ and $(A,P)\mapsto0$ otherwise then $N$ can be recognized as: $$N:=\sum_{i=1}^{100}A_i$$ and we linearity of expectation and symmetry we find indeed that $\mathbb EN=100\times0.3=30$. So you are correct for question b).

c)

Likewise we can prescribe $P_{i}:S\to\mathbb R$ as $(A,P)\mapsto 1$ if $i\in P$ and $(A,P)\mapsto0$ otherwise and then $M$ can be recognized as $$M:=\sum_{i=1}^{100}A_i(1-P_i)$$

Uptil now you only calculated $\mathbb EA_i(1-P_i)$ but to be found is $\mathbb EM$. Again use linearity of expectation and symmetry.